# Rails горизонтальное расположение simple-form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form

Как сделать, чтобы поле для ввода и кнопка располагались на одной строке?

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :id%>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Стилизуйте форму и элементы, присвоив им классы. Например, так:

```css
.inline-form__input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.inline-form__submit {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <div class="inline-form">
    <%= f.input :id, class: 'inline-form__input'%>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: 'inline-form__submit' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Что-то не меняется ничего. Забыл сказать, что форма создана с bootstrap-sass

Answer (score 0):

Если используется bootstrap-sass, то можно так:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, html: {class: 'form-inline'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :id%>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Подробнее про bootsrap [тут](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#inline-forms) и про simple form [тут](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#bootstrap)